# Do indexes match appl to exact fields or include partials as well?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I have an index on the fields below in mongodb:

```
current_plates_partial_end_index = IndexModel([
            ("p1", ASCENDING),
            ("l1", ASCENDING),
            ("l2", ASCENDING),
            ("l3", ASCENDING)
        ], name="current_plates_partial_end_index")
```

Will this index apply to a partial subset say `p1, l2, l3` or do the fields have to be included for the index to be used (`p1, l1, l2, l3`)?

I need to create some new indexes for free text based searching and I dont want to create duplications on indexes I already have.

Thanks

Comment: This is about Compound Indexes. _"Will this index apply to a partial subset..."_: this is called as Index Prefixes: [compound index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes).

Comment: "... indexes for free text based searching...": for this see [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html) and [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html).